# Create an array with size N at compile time by passing N in a constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, constexpr, state-machine

I'm trying to make a state machine that is build at compile time. I've already got a working version by using a lot of template parameters. Now I want to reduce the amount of template parameters and move part of it to constexpr constructors.

```
template<typename EventT, typename StateT>
class ConstStateMachine
{
public:
    constexpr ConstStateMachine(const std::initializer_list<StateDefinition<EventT, StateT>>& states) : 
        _states{ states }
    {        
    }

private:    
    const StateDefinition<EventT, StateT> _states[];
};
```

The code above shows a simplified version of the state machine. I want to specify the size of the array in the constexpr constructor. I know I cloud use templates and make something like this:

```
template<typename EventT, typename StateT, typename ...States>
class ConstStateMachine
{
    const std::tuple<States...> _states;
};
```

and expand the tuple in an initializer list or something but I don't want any other template parameter except for EventT and StateT.

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: You might be interested in [STTCL](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl).

Comment: *Create an array with size N at compile time* -- `std::array<SomeType, N>`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't use `std::array` because N is not a template parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It's not possible.  You'll at least need to add a size template parameter.